# Share a page on facebook that is only retrieved through a redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook

The links on my page go through a click tracking service that logs the user and redirects to the real page.  I'm trying to share the links on facebook using the Facebook Share javascript plugin on my page.
The plugin scrapes the click tracking service page, instead of the "real" page that the click tracking service redirects to.

Is there a way to share the redirected page, and not the click tracking service page?

Comment: you can add og:meta to the redirector to make the preview look like the real page. or use a hidden frame on the real page to ping the redirector.

Comment: There are tons of links, I wouldn't be able to configure an og:meta that fits all pages.  I also don't own the pages that the links point to, so I can't put a hidden frame on them.

Comment: you have to template the ogmeta by fetching the page and harvesting it, just like facebook does, to make each page unique. caching helps.

Comment: I was hoping there was an option to pass into the plugin to tell it to follow to the redirect.

Comment: not sure how you redirect, but a server-side redirect might work better than js or meta, and then the html doesn't matter because there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) tell us that you can identify the scraper by the following user agent:

```
"facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```

If a client is a scraper, your tracking service could answer with a 301 redirect to the real page.

Comment: ...but won't this mean that the user will never go through my click service because the browser will treat the 301 as permanent?

Comment: Only if your user has the same user agent as the facebook scraper. Your tracking service has to check the user agent. It should send the 301 redirect only if the user agent is equal to the user agent of the facebook scraper.

Comment: I meant to say that the browser will cache the 301, therefore making it permanent.

Comment: Then again, it's Facebook's scraper, not the user's browser that is hitting the click tracking service when creating the share link.  So I shouldn't have to worry about the user's browser caching the 301.

Comment: That's right. I don't think there will be a problem.

Comment: Is there any reason that a 301 would work but not a 302 (temporary redirect)?

Comment: There is no important reason, but the Facebook scraper does not need to visit the tracking page again.